# When can a cond var be used to synchronize its own destruction/unmapping?

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, posix, condition-variable

According to POSIX,

> It shall be safe to destroy an initialized condition variable upon which no threads are currently blocked.

Further, the signal and broadcast operations are specified to unblock one/all threads blocked on the condition variable.

Thus, it seems to me the following forms of self-synchronized destruction should be valid, i.e. calling `pthread_cond_destroy`:

1. Immediately after a successful signal, in either the waiting or the signaling thread, when exactly one thread is blocked on the cond var.
2. Immediately after a successful broadcast, in either any waiting thread or the broadcasting thread.

Of course this assumes no further waiters will arrive and no further signals shall be performed afterwards, which the application is responsible for guaranteeing if using `pthread_cond_destroy`.

Am I correct that destruction is valid in these situations? And are there other self-synchronized destruction scenarios to be aware of with condition variables?

Finally, for process-shared cond vars where unmapping the shared mapping without destruction might make sense, is it reasonable to expect unmapping to be valid in the same contexts destruction would be valid, or must further synchronization be performed if multiple threads in the same process (address space) are using the same mapping and want to unmap it in one of the above contexts?

Comment: Bounty time is almost up and I really don't have any candidates to accept...

Comment: Do you have a real program that depends on this?

Comment: I've encountered test code that asserts that it works, and I'm trying to assess whether these tests are valid and whether my implementation of condition variables needs to handle such usage.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think that most of your assumptions are correct. Returning from `pthread_cond_signal` or `pthread_cond_broadcast` does not indicate that any of the threads are yet "unblocked" from the condition variable, i.e that the threads that are to be unblocked don't need access to that variable anymore. The standard only says "shall unblock" and not "on successful return from this call they will be unblocked". The later would be very restrictive for implementations, so there is probably a good reason that this is formulated as it is.

So I think from the scenarios you describe only one is valid, namely the case were the solely blocked thread or process destroys the condition after being woken up.

Comment: Interestingly, the glibc/NPTL tests (e.g. tst-cond20.c) specifically assert that the condition variable is immediately destroyable after broadcast returns. This is in contrast to NPTL's mutex and semaphore implementations whose destruction is completely impossible to synchronize.

Comment: This may be a special feature of that implementation that they are eager to maintain, there are certainly upsides to it. But I don't think that you can or should rely on that in a general context. Maintaining that feature could really be a burden on platforms that don't have a good system support for lock structures.

Comment: As for your answer, while I would hope from an implementation standpoint you're right, I'm hesitant to accept this explanation. Surely when the standard says `memcpy` "shall copy N bytes...", it means this action will be completed by the time `memcpy` returns. I don't see how "shall unblock (all|at least one) thread[s]" automatically involves a special relaxation regarding when the unblocking takes place...

Comment: @R.. the relevant standard (C in this case) says for `memcpy`: "The memcpy function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the
object pointed to by s1." No shall, no nothing it just does it. The semantics of synchronous / asynchronous events in a thread system are quite subtle (as you know :) Usually POSIX makes it quite explicit if a before / after relation between events in different threads is expected.

Comment: Perhaps choosing a function from the C standard was a bad example. If we look at `kill`, which "shall send a signal...", it's later spelled out under what conditions the signal must be delivered before `kill` returns. Do you have any examples where something that "shall" happen clearly doesn't actually happen before the function returns?

Comment: `pthread_cancel` is a good example. It says "shall request that" and afterwards it states that this is an asynchronous operation. So yes, I maintain that the POSIX standard defines very well places where requires a certain ordering or where asynchronism is permitted. Since here there is no specification you simply can't assumed anything and from an application perspective you have to be ready to deal with the worst case scenario.

Comment: As for `pthread_cancel`, I'm pretty sure `pthread_cancel(pthread_self());` followed by a call to any cancellation point without disabling cancellation requires cancellation to be acted upon, i.e. the cancellation request is required to be pending when `pthread_cancel` returns...

Comment: Indeed, "Whenever a thread has cancelability enabled and a cancellation request has been made with that thread as the target, and the thread then calls any function that is a cancellation point (such as pthread_testcancel() or read()), the cancellation request shall be acted upon before the function returns." So the language "shall request" is not giving the implementation liberty to put the operation off until later; rather, a "request" for cancellation has formal meaning in terms of how cancellation is specified in 2.9.5.

Comment: By the way, I hope I'm not coming across as too argumentative/stubborn here. I'm rather split on whether your answer is right or not, but I want a more rigorous argument either way. Perhaps I should get in the habit of annoying the Austin Group with interpretation requests...

Comment: Open POSIX Test Suite test `pthread_cond_destroy/2-1.c` also asserts that a cond var can be immediately destroyed and clobbered after broadcast by the broadcasting thread. This should not be taken as authoritative, since I've found this test suite asserting a number of other dubious or outright-wrong claims, but it does indicate that at least somebody other than Ulrich Drepper thinks self-synchronized destruction of this form should be well-defined...

Comment: @R.. it all ends up being a question of interpretation. So as an application programmer I would not rely on this, and always have some sort of reference count around. As an implementation programmer in turn I would go for the other side and try to implement conds such that they can be destroyed as you describe. But as things stand no side can rely on a specific behavior.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with your interpretation (and that of the Open POSIX test suite) of this language, usage will be implementation dependent.  As such, here is a quick rundown of some of the major implementations:

### Safe

- **nptl** - `pthread_cond_destroy()` will return `EBUSY` if there are threads still blocked on the condition.  Destruction responsibility will pass to the threads that are signaled by not unblocked.
- **pthread-win32 MSVC** - `pthread_cond_destroy()` will return `EBUSY` if there are threads still blocked on the condition.  Threads that are signaled but not unblocked will be executed before `pthread_cond_destroy()` returns control to the application.

---

### Safe but blocking

- **Darwin libc-391** - `pthread_cond_destroy()` will return `EBUSY` if there are threads still blocked on the condition.  No provisions are made for blocked but signaled threads.
- **dietlibc 0.27** - `pthread_cond_destroy()` will return `EBUSY` if there are threads still blocked on the condition.  No provisions are made for blocked but signaled threads.

---

### Possibly not safe

- **Android** - Depends on system implementation of `__futex_wake_ex` to be synchronous.  Thus `pthread_cond_broadcast()` must block until all threads have woken (but not released their mutex).
- **various win32 implementations** - Many rely on the `PulseEvent()` function to implement `pthread_cond_broadcast()`.  This has a [known race condition](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/win32-cv-1.html)

---

### Oddballs

- **OSKit 0.9** - Safe but returns `EINVAL` if `pthread_cond_destroy()` is called on a condition variable that is still referenced

---

***Edit***

The major issue, if I read your comments correctly is whether the `pthread_cond_wait()` can access the condition variable *before* it returns but *after* it is unblocked.  And the answer is **yes**.  The routine assumes that its arguments will remain valid.

This means that after broadcasting, your thread cannot assume that the condition variable is unused by other threads.

When you call `pthread_cond_broadcast()`, you do not acquire the associated mutex lock.  While the threads waiting on your condition variable will execute sequentially, each acquiring the associated mutex in series.  Because your waiters may block each other, your broadcasting thread may continue executing while waiters are still in `pthread_cond_wait()` blocked on the mutex (but not waiting for the condition).

---

***Edit 2***

> [...]is it reasonable to expect unmapping to be valid in the same contexts destruction would be valid?

I don't think that this is a reasonable expectation based on the reasoning in Edit 1.  Additional synchronization would definitely be required if you are precluded from using `pthread_cond_destroy()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not looking for whether `pthread_cond_destroy` is "safe" in the sense of reporting that the cond var is still busy (not required). Rather, I'm asking whether the cond var *formally* can be considered to still have blocked waiters after a signal/broadcast that's specified to "unblock" them returns.

Comment: In that case, yes the broadcast does not ensure that there are no waiters.  Between the moment you broadcast and the moment the routine returns, additional waiters can accumulate.  So while all extant waiters are unblocked by the broadcast, there are no guarantees that by the time the function returns, the condition variable is unused.

Comment: "additional waiters can accumulate" depends on your program; it's certainly possible that you can ensure that case cannot happen. For example if each waiter increments a counter protected by the mutex before waiting, and if you call the broadcast with the mutex held once that count has reached the number of threads that could be waiting, then you know no further waiters can arrive. There are many other such scenarios.

Comment: That is very true.  But POSIX makes no requirements as such.  So I think that by the standard, the cond var __can__ still be formally required by elements of an arbitrary program.

Comment: As an addendum, many implementations use a mutex __in__ the condition variable structure that gets locked before the `pthread_cond_wait()` returns but after the user mutex is locked.  The problem is now that multiple waiters will block on the user mutex while the thread that calls `pthread_cond_broadcast()` returns.  The threads that sequentially acquire the user mutex will still require a valid condition variable after they unblock, so an arbitrary program cannot formally consider the condition variable unused after the broadcast

Comment: @Seth "_a mutex in the condition variable structure that gets locked before the pthread_cond_wait() returns but after the user mutex is locked._" what for?

Comment: @curiousguy To atomically modify the content of the condition variable (number of waiter, e.g)

Comment: @Seth I see, the number of waiters is a ref count used to prevent premature destruction by `pthread_cond_destroy`?

Comment: @curiousguy While doesn't _have_ to be the case, it is used in more than one implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment (not answer):**

Is that what you have in mind?

Global:

```
// protected by m:
pthread_mutex_t m;
pthread_cond_t c;
bool about_to_pthread_cond_wait = false;
bool condition_waited_on = false;
```

Thread A :

```
pthread_mutex_lock (&m);
{ // locked region
    about_to_pthread_cond_wait = true;
    while (condition_waited_on) {
        // pthread_cond_wait (&m, &c) is decomposed here:
        __pthread_mutex_cond_wait_then_unlock (&m, &c);
            // unlocked region
        pthread_mutex_lock (&m);
    }
}
pthread_mutex_unlock (&m);
```

Thread B:

```
for (bool break_loop = false; !break_loop;) {
    pthread_mutex_lock (&m);
    { // locked region
        condition_waited_on = true;

        if (about_to_pthread_cond_wait) {
            pthread_cond_signal (&c);
            pthread_cond_destroy (&c);
            break_loop = true;
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&m);

    pthread_yield ();
}
```

EDIT:

I assume `pthread_cond_wait (&m, &c);` does:

```
__pthread_mutex_cond_wait_then_unlock (&m, &c);
pthread_mutex_lock (&m);
```

`__pthread_mutex_cond_wait_then_unlock` will being monitoring the signals to the CV, then unlock the mutex, then go to sleep.

If the CV has an internal mutex that `__pthread_mutex_cond_wait_then_unlock` and `pthread_cond_signal` must lock internaly, then I assume `__pthread_mutex_cond_wait_then_unlock` does:

```
pthread_mutex_lock (&c.int_mutex);
{ // locked region for c.int_state
    __register_wakeup_cond (&c.int_state);
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&m);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock (&c.int_mutex);
// will not touch c.int_state any more 

__sleep_until_registered_wakeups ();
```

and `pthread_cond_signal` does:

```
pthread_mutex_lock (&c.int_mutex);
{ // locked region for CV internal state
    __wakeup_registered (&c.int_state);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock (&c.int_mutex);
```

Then `pthread_cond_destroy` will only be called after `__pthread_mutex_cond_wait_then_unlock` has finished using `c.int_state`.

Comment: This example will fail.  You have mutex `m` locked while you signal and then try to destroy the condition.  Because the `pthread_cond_wait()` will not allow thread A to continue until it has acquired sole control of the mutex `m`, your call to `pthread_cond_destroy()` will likely return `EBUSY` and the condition variable will remain intact

Comment: @Seth "_This example will fail_" Do you have any example that will work?

Comment: @Seth Is the assumption of mutual exclusion between `__register_wakeup_cond` and `__wakeup_registered` unreasonable?

Comment: I think that the assumption of uninterrupted execution of consecutive statements is not safe.

Comment: A working example (that is independent of the pthread implementation)  could loop on `pthread_cond_destroy()` until success.  There are other ways as well (obviously).

Comment: @Seth "_the assumption of uninterrupted execution of consecutive statements is not safe_" Hug?

Comment: Sorry, I think I mis-interpreted what you were saying.  `__register_wakeup_cond()` and `__wakeup_registered()` are mutually exclusive in your two functions above.  But you rely on a global structure to maintain your wakeup conditions (where you register them).  POSIX threads maintains the state in the condition variable.